# Debugging Internet Explorer crashes

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, crash

I am not interested in some program that I have to pay for, but I really need a way to debug my website in Internet Explorer.

The url is http://www.tombarrasso.com/final/

The issue with IE's built in debugger is that my webpage crashes IE if you open three scrollers and click the right arrow. In Safari and Firefox all is well, not terribly fast but not terribly slow. But IE completely freezes and crashes, which ruins my chance of using the built in profiler. It is getting to the point I am about to put a message for all IE users telling them to go elsewhere, but I would like to get the site to work because everything else even works in IE6 (crazy).

Comment: Why does your website want to know my location? Suspicious...

Comment: The site location is HTML5 Geolocation, and sorry, IE7 and 8 (not sure about 6, haven't tested it since I've had this issue)

Comment: Dude, I clicked on the web site and went blind :(

Answer (score 1):

Try [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

And on a side note I would recommend changing your color scheme, it isn't easy on the eyes. Here is another resource that could help you with that. [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)

Comment: Thanks! : ) The site is the ugliest thing that I've done, but I want to get functionality down before I do design, because the entire design is controlled using CSS it will be a breeze.